How many ways are there to place "$n+1$" after a non-descent, or at the beginning, of a permutation with $k-2$ descents.
Assume we pick $\pi \in S_n$, and write it on the one-line notation form $\pi = \pi_1 \ldots \pi_n$, where $\pi_i = \pi(i)$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Given a permutation $\pi \in S_n$, we say that $i \in [n-1] := \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ is a descent if $\pi_i > \pi_{i+1}$.
I am wondering how many ways there are, given a $\pi \in S_n$ with $k-2$ descents, to insert the number $n+1$ after a non-descent, or at the beginning.
It seems like it should be $(n-(k-2))+1 = n+3-k$ since we can choose to place it after the $(n-(k-2))$ non-descents, or at the beginning, but the notes I have seem to claim that we have $n+k-2$ choices. Why is that?
Edit: If we take \begin{align*} \pi & \pi_1 \pi_2 \pi_3 \pi_4\\ &= 2143, \end{align*} then $1$ and $3$ are descents, and $2,4$ are non-descents.
If we then want to place "$n+1$" after a non-descent or at the beginning, we can do this the following ways (where each $|$ represents one position allowed, I think):
$$|21|43| \qquad (*).$$ But this is, with $k = 4$ so that we have
\begin{align*}
k-2 &= 4-2\\
2,
\end{align*}
descents, we would by the formula $(n-(k-2))$ have $4-(4-2) = 2$ positions to place "$n+1$", but this is incorrect, it should be $3$ places, by inspecting (*).
So my interpretation is that the notes is (implicitly) excluding allowing one to place something at the end.

Hm, well, perhaps it is as easy as the fact that the descents are in $[n-1] = {1,\ldots,n-1}$, so if there are $k-2$ descents, then the $#$ of non-descents in $[n-1]$ are $(n-1)-(k-2) = n+1-k$, and then we count the beginning as well, so $n+2-k$. But it seems like this is not entirely right, since in fact the last position can be a non-descent, even though it can not be a descent.

I am quite sure the author of the notes means that we exclude allowing the placement of "$n+1$" at the end. The motivation for excluding this case is that this claim is in the context of the proof that $A(n,k+1) = (n-k+2)\cdot A(n,k-1)+k \cdot A(n,k)$ where $A(n,k) = \{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n \;|\; \text{des}(\pi) = k-1\}$.
The reasong being that otherwise, taking the example given in my edit, we would have a non-trivial intersection of the case $(n-k+2) \cdot A(n,k-1)$ and $k \cdot A(n,k)$ by looking at $2143 \mapsto 21435$.
